# CockroachDB CSV import failing due to null column

Tags: cockroachdb

I have a CSV exported from a table in another cockroachDB database. When trying to import this CSV to another cockroachDB instance I get the error

```
could not parse "NULL" as type int
```

The failing column has type INT8 and is nullable. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working, you can add `WITH nullif = 'NULL'` to the end of your `IMPORT TABLE` statement as documented [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/import.html#use-blank-characters-as-null).

It would be nice if this "just worked" in CockroachDB, and I just filed [an issue](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/66783) in the CockroachDB GitHub repo.